# How to pass dymanic tablelayout into xml form in linearlayout?

Tags: java, android

I created a dynamic TableLayout using source in java class(DynamicTableLayout.java) . Using this code

```
public class DynamicTableLayout extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TableLayout layout = new TableLayout (this);
    layout.setLayoutParams( new TableLayout.LayoutParams(4,3) );

    TableLayout.LayoutParams rowLp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            1.0f);

    rowLp.setMargins(6, 0, 0,0);

    TableRow.LayoutParams cellLp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            1.0f);

    cellLp.setMargins(6,0, 0, 0);

    layout.setPadding(3,1,1,1);

    for (int f=0; f<=6; f++) {

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);

       tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
       tr.setPadding(1,1,1,1 );

       TableRow.LayoutParams llp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
       llp.setMargins(2, 0, 0, 0);




       for (int c=0; c<=3; c++) {

           LinearLayout cell = new LinearLayout(this);
           cell.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
           cell.setLayoutParams(llp);//2px border on the right for the cell

            TextView b = new TextView (this);
            b.setText("Sample");
            b.setTextSize(10.0f);

            b.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

            cell.addView(b);
            tr.addView(cell,cellLp);

       } 
        layout.addView(tr,rowLp);

    } 

    super.setContentView(layout);
} }
```

main.xml code is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <LinearLayout 
  android:id="@+id/linear1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/bottom_black_pane"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Color range"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"  
    android:paddingTop="10dp"/>
      </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/linear2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/palette"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/linear2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/linear3"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/bottom_black_pane" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:weightSum="1" android:layout_width="355dp">

<Button 
android:id="@+id/Btn1"
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:text="All" 
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:background="#000000"
android:layout_weight="0.18"/>

<Button android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.18"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/Btn2" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Virbate"></Button>

<Button 
android:id="@+id/Btn2"
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:text="Warm" 
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:background="#000000"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_weight="0.18"/>

<Button 
android:id="@+id/Btn2"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:text="Fresh" 
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:background="#000000"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_weight="0.18"/>

<Button 
android:id="@+id/Btn2"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:text="Calm" 
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:background="#000000"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_weight="0.09"/>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView 
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/horizon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/list_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal" 
  android:weightSum="1">


</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

main class code id

```
public class DuluxColorGridActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);




}
```

}

what will i do to integrate the both layouts together,i want to integrate dynamic layout into main.xml layout in the field linearLayout id=list_parent below i declare. help me to solve this problem.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/list_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal" 
  android:weightSum="1">


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add Custom View to any xml you need to provide absolute path of class `(packagename+ classnaem)` in xml

see [Custom Composite Android Component](http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2011/05/26/custom-composite-android-component/)

**Example To create custom tablelayout**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TableLayout;

public class CustomTableLayout extends TableLayout{

    public CustomTableLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // Write your own code here
    }

}
```

To add the abive view in xml you can use follwoing code

```
<com.sunil.list.item.CustomTableLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
```

Comment: Thank you Sunil Kumar Sahoo but in this layout linearlayout for column is not adding, it shows error to create constructor for linearlayout. how can i solve this problem. please help me